Does the Christian God know His own future and is He unable to change that future?
If the Christian God is omniscient, He knows everything, and if He is omnipotent, He is all powerful. But these two statements seem to be contradictory.  So if a Christian believes that his/her God has these two attributes, aren't these two attributes contradictory as well?
Below is why I think they are contradictory:

If God is all knowing, God is able to know the future of every human being and also of Himself.

But if God knows precisely what He will do at any point in time, does He still have free will?

If God is all powerful, could He make a choice at any particular point in time that is not determined by His omniscience?



@GratefulDisciple transferring OP's comment to the Q for more context:
Note: This is a question on theism in general, and I'm interested in a Christian answer to help me with seeing the logic in holding two seemingly contradictory attributes while preserving God's own free will.  I pose this question with a great respect in the belief of a God and I don't mean any derogation to the faith of Christianity nor do I want to upset the users in this community.

see related questions and study reasonablefaith site of Dr Craig, and chatgpt for basic philosophical and theological questioning https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/101701/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-perspectives-on-gods-sovereignty-omn/102209

@Michael16 Thanks for the reference. I pose my questions with a great respect in the belief of a God. My questions are not derogatory to the faith of christianity I questionon the whole a belief in theism. however, this question has been downvoted twice. I can't see the logic in that, a basic question or not!!

@8Mad0Manc8 Yes, your question is respectful.  Downvoting may mean the question is not clear / useful, but since then 3 users upvoted it.  I tried to make your question clearer with some reorganization and connecting phrases.  Hopefully I still preserve your original meaning.  If so, let's see whether the community has an answer for you.

God is outside time. So there is no such thing as His future.

@GratefulDisciple I know its a tough question however as Michael16 has pointed out about the members of this site on the whole. I do not want upset the users of this site with the nature of the question. If you would like you can close it or I can delete if necessary?

@8Mad0Manc8 The way the site works is that questions and answers are ultimately "owned" by the community, but the site has an obligation to preserve the intent of the questioner and the answerer.  Don't worry about upsetting some vocal users; many silent members would be fine with your question although it's their prerogative to vote up/down.  You have done your part respectfully within the Stack Exchange code of conduct.  It takes a while to get used to an SE site.  Take what you can get out of it while contributing something on your own.

All temporal things are present to God at once (for lack of a better word). It is not like God looks at a timeline and sees events one at a time. All things are present to him.

@LukeHill I get the concept that you are trying to explain. God exist atemporally, outside of time, and for a temporal being, our experience is the absolute total of events that a atemporal being can concieve in the relative creation of a temporal realm with temporal beings. Our experience in this world is relative to an unchanging atemporal 'absolute realm' the realm of God. I guess it's a limitation of a temporal being such as ourselves to ponder and determine the experience of an atemporal being such as God.

God is presumably very happy with everything he has chosen and has no desire to change anything


It is the glory of God to conceal a thing: but the honour of kings is to search out a matter. - Proverbs 25:2

It is not merely within the realm of human reason that matters are to be searched out.  The things of God which can be searched out are concealed within God's self revelation.  Revealed within creation are His eternal power and Godhead.  Revealed within the Bible are His great and precious promises, His attributes, and His purpose in Christ.  Revealed in Jesus is the fullness of the Godhead.

Come now, and let us reason together, saith the LORD: though your sins be as scarlet, they shall be as white as snow; though they be red like crimson, they shall be as wool. - Isaiah 1:18

God has given us the capacity to reason but we are foolish to reason apart from the One who is the Creator, the fountainhead of reality.  We must reason together with God; together with and from His revelation.  Human reason alone is unguided blindness, especially when it is the nature of God which is searched out.

Whom shall he teach knowledge? and whom shall he make to understand doctrine? them that are weaned from the milk, and drawn from the breasts. For precept must be upon precept, precept upon precept; line upon line, line upon line; here a little, and there a little: - Isaiah 28:9-10

God's self-revelation is there for the humble and contrite little child to discover line upon line and precept upon precept.  By this are they weaned from the milk and breast of the Word unto the meat and bread of sound doctrine.  This same line and precept brings about the staggering of the proud reasoner who goes beyond what is built by line and precept.
It is said that God inhabits eternity thus shattering the philosophies of the likes of Dr. Craig who claims that, at Creation, God abandoned a timeless state and entered a temporal state.  Such "reasoning" has abandoned the anchor point of line and precept and floats, adrift on the fickle sea of the vain imaginations of man.  God presently inhabits eternity.  We must reason from there.

Known unto God are all his works from the beginning of the world. - Acts 15:18

and

Remember this, and shew yourselves men: bring it again to mind, O ye transgressors. 
Remember the former things of old: for I am God, and there is none else; I am God, and there is none like me, Declaring the end from the beginning, and from ancient times the things that are not yet done, saying, My counsel shall stand, and I will do all my pleasure: - Isaiah 46:8-10

God declares the end from the beginning; and from ancient times the things that are not yet done.  There are no limiting factors introduced here.  His complete foreknowledge is given as one irrefutable demonstration of His singularity: "I am God, and there is none like me, Declaring the end from the beginning".  Theologies that limit His foreknowledge have abandoned line and precept and are fashioning God after the image of man.
It is omniscience by which God knows all that He will do.  It is omniscient foreknowledge of every human choice, every natural event from tectonic to Brownian movement, and the interplay of same and all which meshes with His omnipotence by which God absolutely accomplishes everything He desires regardless of the apparent random or fickle nature of motion and choice.

And he said, Lay not thine hand upon the lad, neither do thou any thing unto him: for now I know that thou fearest God, seeing thou hast not withheld thy son, thine only son from me. - Genesis 22:12

Interpreting this verse apart from the line and precept of God's full omniscience leads to error.  It is line and precept by which further revelation is to be understood:  We must reason together with Him.  Regardless of how a mere 3 ancient Hebrew tenses are clumsily rendered into 12 English tenses, the intended meaning cannot be that God has learned something previously unknown to Him.
Similarly when God asked Adam "Where art thou?" as Adam hid in the Garden it is a departure from line and precept to understand God as truly without this knowledge in the asking.  The result of building upon other than the foundation of line and precept is theological structure without secure foundation.
OP asks "But if God knows precisely what He will do at any point in time, does He still have free will?" and, in asking, supposes that God can only have free will if He is not omniscient.  The Bible declares that He both foreknows and performs all that pleases Him.  God knows everything and does whatever He wants.  Let the sinner with the darkened mind offer himself to God as a living sacrifice and reason together with God from there and let his mind be transformed thereby.

For the invisible things of him from the creation of the world are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even his eternal power and Godhead; so that they are without excuse: Because that, when they knew God, they glorified him not as God, neither were thankful; but became vain in their imaginations, and their foolish heart was darkened. Professing themselves to be wise, they became fools, 
And changed the glory of the uncorruptible God into an image made like to corruptible man - Romans 1:20-23

There is no sound reasoning about God that separates itself from God's revelation of Himself line upon line, precept upon precept, here a little and there a little.  Separation from these causes one to "go, and fall backward, and be broken, and snared, and taken".

+1 for Proverbs 25:2 quote. That was going to be my starting point for an answer. You saved me the time!

Eastern Orthodox perspective time :)



If God is all knowing, God is able to know the future of every human being and also of Himself.

But if God knows precisely what He will do at any point in time, does He still have free will?

If God is all powerful, could He make a choice at any particular point in time that is not determined by His omniscience?





God does not know the future as a clairvoyant predictor. He knows the future insofar as he is already there. The former is incompatible with free will, the latter is not.

That is to say, you are subjecting God to the limitations of time (Causality). God is outside of time. If our entire spacetime universe was a line on a piece of paper, God would be the paper.
All of time is then an eternal present moment, which is why we can experience heaven and the things to come here in this life. It is why the liturgy is a timeless moment as well. But that is a separate topic.
Please see this question and the accepted answer for more details. It mentions free will of creatures but the quotes from John of Damascus and Hebrews 4:13 are related to this as well.

This understanding of God's omniscience relates to a certain extent to the Orthodox understanding of time, which generally holds that time as we understand it has no meaning for God. "Foreknowledge of the future is, strictly speaking, a spiritual vision, because for God the future is the present. (guest37, Feb 8th 2018)


Short answer: The Christian God is outside of the limitations of time that you impose in your question. Future, past, and present have no meaning if you are outside of time. The easiest way for us to understand it is to think of it as all of time, is an eternal moment in the present.
Think of the book "Flatland" by Edwin Abbott Abbott, a 2D shape person encounters a 3D shape person and proposes a 4D world as well. I expect a 4D shape person would be even stranger to the 2D shape person. How much more so is God to us?

If every event of Gods creation is the present for God. What is the future and past experience for God, if God experiences a present? I know this is question of an atemporal experience and we are temporal beings.

Fundamentally God is unknowable except for what he has already shown us. He has shown us that he is eternal and outside of the limitations of Time. Our best way to understand that is as an "eternal present moment" which of course is not possible inside of the limitations of time. God is outside of time. This is why I mentioned flatland. Imagine you are 3D looking on a 2D world. You can see impossible things like around edges because you have a topdown view. God is similar, beyond time he has a "topdown" view of our whole universe. (both space and time)

I lean to the approach the Martin Luther took on God’s attributes.
On first glance I understand that God is wholly outside of time so the question is based on a false premise. However at the same time I doubt any human elaborate logic around God’s attributes as trustworthy, so won’t really argue my own. The only thing that is trustworthy is stated in 1 Tm 1:15

Here is a trustworthy saying that deserves full acceptance: Christ
Jesus came into the world to save sinners —of whom I am the worst.

Considering this is the case I follow the lead of Luther who said:

An investigation of this essential and divine will, or of the Divine
Majesty, must not be pursued but altogether avoided.

and also

God is immutable and unchanging in His counsel from eternity. He sees
and knows all things; but He does not reveal them to the godly except
at His own fixed time, so that they themselves may see them too.

and also

I follow this general rule: to avoid as much as possible any questions
that carry us to the throne of the Supreme Majesty. It is better and
safer to stay at the manger of Christ the Man. For there is very
great danger in involving oneself in the mazes of the Divine Being

Note: I switched order of these quotations to suit this answer but they all come from his commentary of Genesis chapter 6:6 treated the concept of anthropomorphism.
In otter words I am not a smart man when I approach God. I am a dumb sinner. However my joy is looking at the child in a manger, whereby the infinite all powerful all knowing God took human flesh to die for me. He is just as much my child as he was Mary’s and this sparks a flame of holy love even in a forgiven soul like me and everyone else who comes to Him.
The wise men, yeah, even the pseudo scientific dark minded pagans knew enough to avoid Jerusalem and its holy men, Rome and its great philosophers and even their own occultism, and inquire simply and only, ‘Where is the child born King of the Jews?’
This is the question that brings light! to a dark land and rescues men from human reason altogether. Don’t trust anything else or anyone who says anything different, even if they be an apostle or an angel.

I think this is a very good and interesting question, which would/will probably receive different answers from different views on the subject.
Furthermore, it also depends on whether you see God as a temporal being within His creation, or an atemporal (timeless) being altogether. (A great exposition of the philosophical concepts can be found here).  In the latter instance, the question of "future" doesn't pose itself for God, for time doesn't play a role in his existence - he doesn't have a past/presence/future but a state of eternal existence that is timeless. For what follows, I will go with the proposal of Dr. Craig which states that God, with triggering the creative act, switched from a timeless state to a temporal state to be united with His creation and be able to operate in it. Why? Because of all the presented possibilities, it's the one that makes most sense to me. That doesn't mean that it is necessarily the true reality of things! Does God know EVERYTHING if He is in this temporal state?
Most Christian views attribute both omniscience and omnipotence to God. The difference often lies with the understanding of the terms "omniscience" and "omnipotence" and what they entail.
What many people don't get is that God is in full control of His powers. He hence can use his power of omniscience the way he wants, or not at all -  however He deems fit.
Infinite exercise of foreknowledge?
If God doesn't know all future events and circumstances fully (including about Himself) then he isn't really perfectly omniscient, is He?
The argument that God’s not foreknowing all future events and circumstances in full detail would evidence imperfection on his part is, in reality, an arbitrary view of perfection. Perfection, correctly defined, does not demand such an absolute, all-embracing extension, inasmuch as the perfection of anything actually depends upon its measuring up completely to the standards of excellence set by one qualified to judge its merits.
Ultimately, God’s own will and good pleasure, not human opinions or concepts, are the deciding factors as to whether anything is perfect.​— Deuteronomy 32:4; 2 Samuel 22:31; Isaiah 46:10.
To illustrate this, God’s almightiness is undeniably perfect and is infinite in capacity. (1 Chronicles 29:11, 12; Job 36:22; 37:23) Yet his perfection in strength does not require him to use his power to the full extent of his omnipotence in any or in all cases. Clearly he has not done so; if he had, not merely certain ancient cities and some nations would have been destroyed, but the earth and all in it would have been obliterated long ago by God’s executions of judgment, accompanied by mighty expressions of disapproval and wrath, as at the Flood and on other occasions. (Genesis 6:5-8; 19:23-25, 29; compare Exodus 9:13-16; Jeremiah 30:23, 24.)
God’s exercise of his might is therefore not simply an unleashing of limitless power but is constantly governed by his purpose and, where merited, tempered by his mercy.​—Nehemiah 9:31; Psalm 78:38, 39; Jeremiah 30:11; Lamentations 3:22; Ezekiel 20:17.
Similarly, if, in certain respects, God chooses to exercise his infinite ability of foreknowledge in a selective way and to the degree that pleases him, then assuredly no human or angel can rightly say: “What are you doing?” (Job 9:12; Isaiah 45:9; Daniel 4:35)
It is therefore not a question of ability, what God can foresee, foreknow, and foreordain, for “with God all things are possible.” (Matthew 19:26) The question is what God sees fit to foresee, foreknow, and foreordain, for “everything that he delighted to do he has done.”​—Psalm 115:3.
Selective exercise of foreknowledge. The alternative to predestinarianism, the selective or discretionary exercise of God’s powers of foreknowledge, would have to harmonize with God’s own righteous standards and be consistent with what he reveals of himself in his Word. In contrast with the theory of predestinarianism, a number of texts point to an examination by God of a situation then current and a decision made on the basis of such examination.

At Genesis 11:5-8 God is described as directing his attention
earthward, surveying the situation at Babel, and, at that time,
determining the action to be taken to break up the unrighteous
project there.

After wickedness developed at Sodom and Gomorrah, God advised Abraham
of his decision to investigate (by means of his angels) to “see
whether they act altogether according to the outcry over it that has
come to me, and, if not, I will know it.” (Ge 18:20-22; 19:1)

God spoke of ‘becoming acquainted with Abraham,’ and after Abraham
went to the point of attempting to sacrifice Isaac, God said,
“For now I do know that you are God-fearing in that you have not
withheld your son, your only one, from me.”​—Genesis 18:19; 22:11, 12;
compare Nehemiah 9:7, 8; Galatians 4:9.


Selective foreknowledge means that God could choose not to foreknow indiscriminately all the future acts of his creatures. This would mean that, rather than all history from creation onward being a mere rerun of what had already been foreseen and foreordained, God could with all sincerity set before the first human pair the prospect of everlasting life in an earth free from wickedness.
His instructions to his first human son and daughter to act as his perfect and sinless agents in filling the earth with their offspring and making it a paradise, as well as exercising control over the animal creation, could thus be expressed as the grant of a truly loving privilege and as his genuine desire toward them​—not merely as the giving of a commission that, on their part, was foredoomed to failure.
God’s arranging for a test by means of “the tree of the knowledge of good and bad” and his creation of “the tree of life” in the garden of Eden also would not be meaningless or cynical acts, made so by his foreknowing that the human pair would sin and never be able to eat of “the tree of life.”​—Genesis 1:28; 2:7-9, 15-17; 3:22-24.
To offer something very desirable to another person on conditions known beforehand to be unreachable is recognized as both hypocritical and cruel. The prospect of everlasting life is presented in God’s Word as a goal for all persons, one possible to attain. After urging his listeners to ‘keep on asking and seeking’ good things from God, Jesus pointed out that a father does not give a stone or a serpent to his child that asks for bread or a fish. Showing his Father’s view of disappointing the legitimate hopes of a person, Jesus then said: “Therefore, if you, although being wicked, know how to give good gifts to your children, how much more so will your Father who is in the heavens give good things to those asking him?”​—Matthew 7:7-11.
Thus, the invitations and opportunities to receive benefits and everlasting blessings set before all men by God are bona fide. (Matthew 21:22; James 1:5, 6) He can in all sincerity urge men to ‘turn back from transgression and keep living,’ as he did with the people of Israel. (Ezekiel 18:23, 30-32; compare Jeremiah 29:11, 12.) Logically, he could not do this if he foreknew that they were individually destined to die in wickedness. (Compare Acts 17:30, 31; 1 Timothy 2:3, 4.) As God YHWH told Israel: “Nor said I to the seed of Jacob, ‘Seek me simply for nothing, you people.’ I am YHWH, speaking what is righteous, telling what is upright. . . . Turn to me and be saved, all you at the ends of the earth.”​—Isaiah 45:19-22.
In a similar vein, the apostle Peter writes: “God is not slow respecting his promise [of the coming day of reckoning], as some people consider slowness, but he is patient with you because he does not desire any to be destroyed but desires all to attain to repentance.” (2 Peter 3:9) If God already foreknew and foreordained millenniums in advance precisely which individuals would receive eternal salvation and which individuals would receive eternal destruction, it may well be asked how meaningful such ‘patience’ of God could be and how genuine his desire could be that ‘all attain to repentance.’
The inspired apostle John wrote that “God is love,” and the apostle Paul states that love “hopes all things.” (1 John 4:8; 1 Corinthians 13:4, 7) It is in harmony with this outstanding, divine quality that God should exercise a genuinely open, kindly attitude toward all persons, he being desirous of their gaining salvation, until they prove themselves unworthy, beyond hope. (Compare 2 Peter 3:9; Hebrews 6:4-12.) Thus, the apostle Paul speaks of “God’s kindness [that] is meant to lead you to repentance”​ —Ro 2:4-6.
Finally if, by God’s foreknowledge, the opportunity to receive the benefits of Christ Jesus’ ransom sacrifice were already irrevocably sealed off from some, perhaps for millions of individuals, even before their birth, so that such ones could never prove worthy, it could not truly be said that the ransom was made available to all men. (2 Corinthians 5:14, 15; 1 Timothy 2:5, 6; Hebrews 2:9) The impartiality of God is clearly no mere figure of speech. “In every nation the man that fears [God] and works righteousness is acceptable to him.” (Acts 10:34, 35; Deuteronomy 10:17; Romans 2:11) The option is actually and genuinely open to all men “to seek God, if they might grope for him and really find him, although, in fact, he is not far off from each one of us.” (Acts 17:26, 27)
There is no empty hope or hollow promise set forth, therefore, in the divine exhortation at the end of the book of Revelation inviting: “Let anyone hearing say: ‘Come!’ And let anyone thirsting come; let anyone that wishes take life’s water free.”​—Revelation 22:17.
As for God Himself, the same principle applies. God does react when necessary (Zechariah 2:8). God reacts to prayers (Psalm 34:18; 138:6). These reactions are not foreseen in detail in advance, but ad-hoc reactions of God appropriate in His view. He thus can choose to not know in fullness all steps he will be taking just as He can choose how to use His power of omniscience however He sees fit. In the temporal state, God lives in the present and experiences it with us. I fully trust Him that He knows enough to make sure that His purpose will be fulfilled. That doesn't mean that He has to know everything to the infinite detail - neither of our Future nor of His own.

Three things:  1) Complete foreknowledge does not = predestinarianism:  Genuine human choice remains.  2) Dr. Craig is wrong that God left a timeless state to take on a temporal state at creation.  Isaiah 57:15 "For thus said the high and exalted One, Inhabiting eternity, and holy is His name:", 3) By what mechanism does God foreknow which things He can safely not foreknow?

Can you please provide the link to the source you seem to be quoting from?  The word "predestinarianism" and the expression "selective exercise of foreknowledge" are in Jehovah's Witness articles I've read.

This is a JW article on 'selective exercise of foreknowledge, the alternative to predestinarianism': https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1970567

@MikeBorden - 1) I didn’t say that predestination = complete foreknowledge. Foreordination does. However if all future choices are foreknown, no free choice of humans would ever surprise God. No choice could either please or shock God - the Bible clearly shows though that choices did. Plus - why lay choices in front of people if you exactly know the choice that will be made?
2) Isaiah 58:15 only shows that God lives or “dwells” forever. The “forever” here being an infinite timespan, an not a metaphysical location!

@MikeBorden- With Internet access, you have the power to get to know everything that is freely available on the internet - by what mechanism do you chose what to read/view and what not to? You chose freely- It’s God’s free choice as well. He can get to know what he needs and/or wants to know using the power of omniscience. For the rest, he sees the present of all living thing and stays in that present. Free choices surprise Him pleasantly or may disappoint Him.

I have to choose what to find on the internet because of my severe limitations. I don't believe that God has any of my limitations. If God is constantly reacting to unforeseen evil choices then he is not sovereign.  It seems as though you're redefining omniscience to mean that God can know whatever he wants rather than God does know everything.

@MikeBorden - God's reactions to men's free will are sovereign - God will always accomplish His purpose, no matter what men will do. That's what being sovereign means. There is no display of sovereignty needed if everything goes exactly as planned - God doesn't bend His own rules, but can take detours of his originally planned path if necessary to still get to His desired outcome. There are indeed no limitations to what God can do. That doesn't mean that God doesn't limit himself (he has unlimited power too - imagine he would use that totally all the time).

Imagine you would have no limits in taking in what is freely available on the internet. Would you consume nasty/vile stuff? Of course you wouldn't, even if you could. You won't even go and take a glimpse - why? Because you detest it and it doesn't help you. Same with God? Do you think he knows in advance all the people aborting babies, all the child abusers, all the vile things humans are doing in detail? God is far from those things (Psalm 138:6) - They don't help His purpose. He provided the means for universal redemption "once and for all". The details are relevant only for final judgement.

I simply don't define who God is by imagining what I can or cannot do.  This results in a god fashioned after the image of corruptible man (Romans 1:23).  "To whom then will ye liken me, or shall I be equal? saith the Holy One.", "there is no searching of his understanding.". - Isaiah 40.  When we imagine limitations of His wisdom, knowledge, and understanding we are in error. "For if our heart condemn us, God is greater than our heart, and knoweth all things." - 1 John 3:20.  Once again, there are no limitations stated or implied about God's knowledge.

"knoweth all things"   γινωσκω (ginosko)  a primary verb meaning to know,; to have and handle data in one's mind.   When used in perfect form it means to come to know.  In 1 John 3:20 it is present, active, indicative which means God currently, actively, absolutely knows all things.   All things simply means all things.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
